# what are the chances of drawing the same pairs/matches (in different order) out of a pool of 16? (Regarding the UEFA-CL drawings)

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the probability of this exact same Champions League draw?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262629/what-is-the-probability-of-this-exact-same-champions-league-draw)

sorry for being a math noob ;). You might've heard that todays results of the UEFA Championsleague round-of-16-draw we're the same as in yesterdays rehearsal.

Rehearsal:
http://www.express.de/image/view/2012/11/20/21156802,17059041,highRes,maxh,480,maxw,480,6940_4966161829891_1190576253_n.jpg

Live:
http://www.express.de/image/view/2012/11/20/21157400,17052847,highRes,maxh,480,maxw,480,DAB1013_20121220.jpg

(sorry, im not yet allowed to post images :/)

What are the chances of this happening?

Thanks :)

Comment: Plus the Barcelona head coach Tito Vilanova being diagnosed with a return of a cancer for which he already had surgery. You can't tell me that's a coincidence.

Comment: shame on me, sorry :(