# How should teams be paired for first round of Champions League?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

In the draw for the round of 16 of the Champions League football tournament, the eight group winners are seeded, and the eight group runners-up are unseeded. The seeded teams are drawn against the unseeded teams, with the seeded teams hosting the second leg. Teams from the same group or the same association cannot be drawn against each other.

Unfortunately, this is not the description of an algorithm. I have seen draws, but it didn't make it clear to me what exactly their mechanism is. So, to translate it to a more combinatorial problem.

Suppose that we are given a bipartite graph that contains at least one perfect matching. What is the algorithm that they use to pick a perfect matching?

[This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262629/what-is-the-probability-of-this-exact-same-champions-league-draw) (mysteriously also asked in December!) seems to suppose implicit that the generated distribution is uniform on the matchings. This is very unlikely from the way the draws are conducted, where teams are drawn against each other from urns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers of "Nom Prenom" in december 2012, in the thread you mention above (and the answers to the different people who wrotes in this thread, including somebody named Igor). Teams pairing are selected one after the other: a team which finished second is selected first, then all valid opponents who finished first (valid in the sense that they have not been selected yet, and if selected, this choice will not lead to an unfeasible pairing for the remaining teams, this is precomputed by a computer) are placed in a bowl and one is selected. Doing so indeed leads to a NON-UNIFORM probability of draws. In particular all probabilities of team pairing that are given on the web are incorrect, reproduced blindly. To get the right probability, you need to emulate all possible draws and do the adequate counting. But this is doable (40 sec on my computer to get the probability of each possible draw and order in which it is generated).

Comment: As you might have seen, the last comment on Nom Prenom's answer is mine, I asked them at the same time when I posed this question if they know for sure that that is the correct algorithm. So I'm asking you the same thing - do you know for sure? How?

Comment: This is what you see when the draw is done live or on videos (you should be able to find them on youtube). No ambiguity. It is clear they anticipate possible impossibilities, because a) the live draw never fails, b) there have been cases where a pairing was selected right away, without putting balls in a bowl, even though there were more than one (immediate) choice. But only one pairing was actually possible at this stage to make further pairings possible.  This happened, for instance, in 2012 when Milan was selected. It was paired directly to Barcelone while more choices "seemed" possible.

Comment: See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t75zUlsPeds. When Milan (which finished second) was selected, it could have been, in principle, be paired with Paris, Barcelone, and Manchester United (which finished first). However, there were still three other teams (which finished second) to pair: Porto, Madrid, Valencia (thus 2 spanish teams), and if either Paris or Manchester was selected, there would remain three teams (which finished first), including two spanish teams (Malaga and Barcelone). So, no matching would have been possible. This is why Milan was paired directly to Barcelone.

Comment: This is quite convincing, but it's not a proof. On the other hand, if they don't provide more information, then all we can rely on is empirical observations. But for example do we know that the computer would not discard a pairing that would limit the further options too much?

Comment: I am not sure to understand: a proof of what? The process they use is clear, and has been this one since the beginning. There is no other way to do a draw that selects team after team, in sequence, instead of a matching as whole. One needs to make sure that all possible opponents are candidates in the bowl for ball selection but, with the additional constraint that, in the subsequent steps, a matching of the remaining teams is still possible. Otherwise, they may need to say "oh, no solution, we need to start again", with no certainty that this process will end soon. But this is live on TV.

Comment: Actually, yes, there are two other solutions. The first suggested by "conspiracy theory" people: the matching is actually preselected a few days before, in a random fashion among all valid matchings or, even worse, by cheating to avoid big teams to meet at this stage. Then, what they show live is just a fake draw, making this matching come out, thanks to freezing balls easy to recognize. The second is as you suggest, with a suboptimal selection of possible opponents (and they would not be aware of the problem), which worked so far, but not always. But I don't see why they would be that stupid?

Comment: On the contrary, I assume that they are so stupid that they don't even realize what possible options are and that their method doesn't give a uniform distribution.

Comment: It is indeed possible that nobody, except a few people like us who did the exercise, know (and care :-) ) that the distribution is not uniform. All media propagate the easy-to-get probabilities such as those given by 2010MisterChip, with the implicit assumption of equal probabilities. As for UEFA, I guess they don't know and don't care. Indeed, that's just a draw! As long as all valid matchings can potentially arise, and probabilities of games do not change too much, this is fine. As for their program to build potential opponents, I would guess it is ok since this is straightforward to do.

Comment: I found a nice simulator: https://inker.github.io/cl-draw/?mode=last16 You can try. You will see how the set of potential opponents is updated after each selection of a team from the first set. And you will quickly find examples where some choices are indeed removed to prevent the absence of matchings for remaining teams. So, no reason to believe this selection of potential opponents can be wrong in UEFA program. How it is implemented is another question, there are many solutions including the brute force one that goes through all precomputed valid matchings and record the potential opponents.

Comment: I hope that whoever made the program at least heard of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem.

Comment: Of course. But this is not by checking Hall's property that you should implement it. It would be too slow. However, if you are interested in Hall's marriage thm in this context, take a look at: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2013.00656.x/full It is a nice popularization effort, even if they don't go to the full computation (I guess they are mathematicians, not programmers). But indeed, every year, as for you, it makes me crazy that no media makes the effort to really understand what is going on. I think I should have written some popularization article too. But where?

Comment: Yeah, of course there are faster methods, but I'm sure Hall can also be checked for such a small instance in less than a second. In fact, probably also the brute force would be fast enough for such a small graph.

Comment: For determining the opponents, on the fly, during one particular draw, time is indeed not an issue. However, if you want to emulate all (8!)² orders to get the right probabilities of all matchings and thus of all games, you cannot afford 1s for each!

Comment: Actually, this is less than (8!)² but you get the idea. This can be a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Define a matching algorithm as "uniform" if and only if every allowable set of pairings is equally likely.

The following mechanism is practical, but **not** uniform, in the sense that matchings of the type $Aa, Bb, Cc, Dd$ are all validly matched against each other and same for the other eight teams, have different probabilities than matchings not satisfying that property:

Draw a seeded team at uniform random.  Pair that seeded team with a randomly drawn non-seeded team; if the teams are from the same group, repeat the non-seeded team draw, then replace the first-drawn non-seeded team.  Repeat on the remaining balls in the two collections, until there is only one left in each collection.  If those last two are from the same group, discard the entire draw and repeat.

Here is a method which is uniform in all allowable match arrangements, and at average, requires about the same number of draws:

Draw the parings for teams $A,B, \ldots,H$ sequentially from the bag containing $a, b, \ldots, h$, ignoring possible disallowed matchups.  Then examing the resulting pairings and if there is an unallowed pairing, discard the entire draw and try again.  The expected value of the number of tries required will be very close to $e$.

So this method is "better", but I will guess that the actual committee either uses a less "perfect" method or, more likely, refuses to disclose its method because it takes bribes or assigns more desirable pairings, and would be vulnerable to this being detected by statistical examination if the purported pairing method were revealed.

Comment: Why would the expected number of draws be very close to $e$ for the second algorithm? If I understand your algorithm correctly, you are proposing to sample a perfect matching from a bipartite graph $G = (U \cup V, E)$ by drawing |U| random pairs from $U\times V$ and starting over if any pair is not in $E$. This is just rejection sampling and clearly gives the right probability, but the probability of *not* rejecting can be exponentially small.