# Maths behind UEFA CL draw

Tags: combinatorics

https://www.statslife.org.uk/sports/467-football-formulae-the-maths-behind-the-uefa-champions-league-draw

According to this site, ....

> Finally, some credit is due to UEFA for avoiding the potential for fiasco these rules create. A naively conducted draw could very easily break down, with a runner-up 'running out' of valid opponents (for example, if the last two teams to be drawn were both Spanish). Fortunately, there is a neat theorem that helps anticipate this situation arising, although its most common example lies in a rather different context: pairing up men and women to get married. While we're not certain, it seems likely that UEFA employed something to this effect to save the embarrassment of an aborted draw.

But the article ends, and it does not explain what this theorem is, what it says, what the assumptions are, etc. Anybody knows?

Comment: Perhaps it's for the same reason Barcelona could commit 5 penalties in a semi-final vs Chelsea and get away with every single one of them.

Comment: I just want to know the theorem man. What is the "different context" that the article is talking about? The stable marriage problem or something?

Comment: From the little that is said it cannot be determined if there really is a theorem that guarantees a pairing of teams.  There are such theorems, but they rest on assumptions (such as equal numbers of men and women in [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem) alluded to).

Answer (score 0):

See the related discussion in [How should teams be paired for first round of Champions League?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050039/how-should-teams-be-paired-for-first-round-of-champions-league?rq=1) (where I cite this paper) and even the previous discussion in 2012 (which led the authors of this paper to write it): [What is the probability of this exact same Champions League draw?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262629/what-is-the-probability-of-this-exact-same-champions-league-draw?rq=1)