# French documentation on rook polynomial

Tags: probability, polynomials

I've found this very interesting topic on how to calculate the chances of draws of the Champions League ([What is the probability of this exact same Champions League draw?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262629/what-is-the-probability-of-this-exact-same-champions-league-draw?newreg=3e354464e28349d190e89392163a9fae)) but I struggle to understand the technique of the rook polynomial used to calculate it.

I've looked at differents english documentations on it but not being fluent in english (I'm french) and not having done "advanced maths" for a while, I'm looking for a french documentation of the rook polynomial to fully understand it.